# Anti C (char + char)

Tags: c

Hello is it possible to add a char to another char like:

```
char *myChar = ("Hello ");
*myChar += ("World!");
printf("%c", *myChar);
```

Thank you!

Comment: It might be a good idea to consider investing in a good textbook. There are *a lot* of issues with just the three lines of code in the question.

Comment: Get yourself a copy of Kernighan & Ritchie's book (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language). It's a masterpiece of technical writing, and belongs at the top of your reading list if you want to learn how to code in C.

Answer (score 3):

Not like this. You have to provide a buffer and use `strcpy` and `strcat` to build the combined string.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to concatenate two strings then use library function `strcat`.

Test program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
   char src[50], dest[50];

   strcpy(src,  "Hello ");
   strcpy(dest, "World");

   strcat(src, dest);

   printf("Concatenated string is : |%s|", src);

   return(0);
}
```

Comment: @dreamlax no, that's not correct. It is UB to modify the string, that doesn't mean it has to be read-only (and some compilers have an option to make literals read-write).

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: The answer has been edited, but in any case, the string would not have enough room, so whether it is modifiable or not, `strcat` alone wouldn't work. Note, I didn't say read-only, just not modifiable (at least, not if you want portable code).

Comment: It should be `strcat(src, dest);` or you get `WorldHello `.

Comment: @Lundin; Corrected now :)

Comment: @dreamlax of course. It's just one of those small things that makes me twitch whenever I see it, and I get on my standards high-horse.

Comment: @haccks The result of `strcat` is in the first argument, in your case `src`. You are printing `dest`...

Comment: @KlasLindbäck; This typo comes in existence after changing `strcat(dest, src);` to `strcat(src, dest);`. I forgot to change `printf`'s argument.

Answer (score -1):

If I take your question literally yes it is possible, your example however is for something else.

You can add 2 chars like,

```
char a = 'a';
char b = 'b';
char result = a + b;
```

You can add 2 char pointers, which will likely to give you an invalid pointer, unless you make sure its not out of bounds.

```
char* str1 = "string1";
char* str2 = "string2";
char* result = str1 + str2;
```

In case of using literals you have to have a temporary storage since the literals are always const.
This is probably the closest you can get:

```
printf("%s%s","Hello ","World");
```

Comment: You cannot add pointers. That's a constraint violation and will not compile.

Comment: Pointer addition requires one operand to be a pointer type and the other to be an integer type.

Comment: Oh yes forgot about that, but if you really want to you can enforce the addition which is not a good thing to do, but even if you add the 2 pointers somehow its not gonna do any good anyways.